# php if-elseif-else/if-else with 3 different statements

Tags: php

I want to request php code `if-else / if-elseif-else`, with this statements:

if `usercode=1` i want to open `file1.php`, but if `usercode=2` i want to open `file2.php` and if `usercode=3` i want to open `file3.php`.

anyone know the php `if-elseif-else/if-else` code with that statements?
i'm so tired to make the code with that 3 statements

> sorry for my bad english language or grammar

Comment: Well you already perfectly described how you would write those conditions. Where is the problem? How does your current code looks like?

Comment: if($usercode==1){
  ///open 1
}
elseif($usercode==2){
 ///open 2
}
elseif($usercode==3){
 ///open 3
}

http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.elseif.php 

`use switch statement is better`

Comment: try this https://3v4l.org/qMtpL and also read this http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.elseif.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well you can do like this :

```
if($usercode==1){
   //open file file1.php
}else if($usercode==2){
   //open file file2.php
}else if($usercode==3){
   //open file file2.php
}else{
   // no file to open (this is default condition)
}
```

Comment: omg, thank you very muchh. you help me with that code. Thank you very much again..... :) i enjoy it ^_^

Comment: Click on the upper triangle where it is written zero(0) in bold on my answer

Comment: @arigohafnan click on up cursor http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-to-upvote-on-stack-overflow

Comment: @aman What do you need this last else for, in this code sample?

Comment: @rafal-kozlowski  this is the default condition  for example if mistakenly user passes the some other value apart from 1,2,3 the the block of code go in the else block and you can alert that user saying ( hey that not the valid input plese pass 1,2 or 3)

Comment: @aman I know what it means :) My question was more about if it is necessary in this code snippet as an answer for the question

Comment: @rafal-kozlowski because you should always assign the default condition to if condition it's best practice

Comment: @aman It is not true. You should always assign a default value for a variable which is manipulated using if-else, but having not used 'else' is a bad practice.

Answer (score 1):

**Using if / elseif** read [this](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.elseif.php) for else if

```
if ($usercode == 1)
{
      //Open file1
}
else if ($usercode == 2)
{
      //Open file2
}
else if ($usercode == 3)
{
      //Open file2
}
```

**Switch**

```
switch ($usercode)
{
      case 1:
            //Open file1
            break;

      case 2:
            //Open file2
            break;

      case 3:
            //Open file3
            break;
}
```